# How can I set the total pages number for the jqx-grid in my js controller programatically?

Tags: javascript, jqxgrid

I get the result count from the server side and this count should be the total pages count.

The count is received correct and it should now be set as the total pages number.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set the total page count in the before processing function of the source that you are defining.
like this

```
 var source =
        {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [
                 { name: 'studentId' },
                 { name: 'studentName' },
                 { name: 'Address' },
                 { name: 'City' },
                 { name: 'Country' }
            ],
            url: 'remote server',

            beforeprocessing: function (data) {
                //refer the below example                  
                source.totalrecords = data[0].TotalRows;
            },

        };
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your answer would be greatly improved if you provide a code example of how to  set the page count, rather than just saying it is possible. His question is "How to accomplish this?"